# Prevent editable QComboBox selection from changing when item list modified

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

I have an editable QComboBox containing a list of ID numbers.

The ID numbers represent devices attached to the system. The devices are frequently added and removed at runtime.

The intent of the editable combo box is to contain, in its list, the list of IDs currently attached, for easy selection, but at the same time allow the user to manually enter IDs of devices not currently present. Also, it's valid to enter an empty string for the ID.

Basically I want to provide the user with a way to enter an arbitrary (or no) ID, with the added bonus of a quick selection of devices currently attached (which changes at runtime).

I am not currently using a list model to maintain the list, I'm just using the QComboBox's add and remove functions.

I need the selection to not change if devices are added or removed. However, I'm running into the following problems:

- When the currently entered ID (either manually or by list selection) is removed from the list, the selection is changed to another ID in the list.
- When the list is empty and an ID is entered manually, or no ID is entered at all, the selection is changed when an ID is added to the list.

Is there a way to make it so that adding and removing items from the combo box never, ever modifies the selection in the edit box? Or even some other UI element that accomplishes my goal?

Comment: Seems easy: don’t remove it if it’s the current selection. As for adding, copy the current line edit content to the list if it doesn’t exist there, set the selection to that item,  and add the new item. You might reevaluate whether the control you use is appropriate. It seems that you’d rather want a plain line edit with a drop down button that opens a selection box that allows the user to copy the ID into the line edit. You may be able to look into the combo box’s attributes and see if some combination will do what you want. Or see the qt source for hints.

Comment: @kuba Good ideas. I think I'll just do the plain edit + drop down button idea, it can show a pop up menu or something, and have a close enough appearance to a combo box that it'll make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before updating the combo box, save the currently selected ID (or the blank string) to a temp. variable. After modifying the combo box contents, check if that ID still exists in the combo box (e.g. with `findText()`). If it does, select it with `setCurrentIndex()`. If it does not, set it with `setCurrentText()` or `setEditText()`.

Comment: That's a good idea too. I already changed it to a line edit + button + popup menu but I'll try this tomorrow to see how smooth it feels.

Comment: @JasonC Note that if you're relying on signals from the `QComboBox` when a selection changes (`currentIndexChanged()` etc), you will probably want to block those signals while adding/removing items and re-setting the `currentIndex` or text (e.g. with `QObject::blockSignals()` or `QSignalBlocker`).

Comment: Your idea worked well. I'm going to stick with the popup menu. But this is a totally working solution and you deserve some points, have a check mark, lol.