# How can we hold on emitting signals from a QComboBox and only emit them if still relevant after exiting a certain code bloc?

Tags: python, qt, signals

Basically, is there a context manager to do something like `holdSignals`, in code such as this:

```py
class MyComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def updateItems():
        with self.holdSignals():
            previous_text = self.currentText()

            # Update comboBox items here

            self.setCurrentText(previous_text)
```

...that would only emit the relevant signals (`currentIndexChanged()`, `currentTextChanged()`, (any signals added in a new version of `Qt`), ...) after exiting? Or maybe some other equivalent construct?

So to be clear, the idea is to avoid emitting any intermediary signals if for example text goes from 'a' to 'b' then to 'a' again, inside that context. Same thing with indexes if items are reordered.

I know I can do this manually using `blockSignals` then reemitting the relevant signals but then I'd be duplicating logic from `Qt` that I would need to keep updated with new versions.

Comment: Maybe another way to do that is if that context manager was designed to handle not changing the user chosen item in the combobox while we rearrange the choices (if the item still exists). So that would take care of the `previous_text` related logic in my example as well.

Comment: Related question but answer is too low level and doesn't take care of signals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725161/prevent-editable-qcombobox-selection-from-changing-when-item-list-modified

Comment: To be clear, such behavior is easy to implement, but I'm wondering if it already exists, since I couldn't find something like that.